# Find record from a specific ID onwards

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

In Rails, I was running a rake task:

```
@shops = Shops.find(:all)
@shops.each do |shop|
  # some task here
end
```

I have 100 records. The task ran 1 to 50, and stopped because of some exception. How can I change my rake task to resume the task, but start running 51 onwards?

Thanks.

Comment: You can pass an `:offset` to find to only select the records that still need work.

Comment: I can make do with this. But for knowledge sake, what if I can't offset, but can only start with certain ID? Dty's solution below can work, but I need to iterate my record 50 times first before it continues.

Comment: Unless you had a "default_scope" in Shop model the order of a SELECT is not guaranteed.

Comment: isn't the task idempotent? is a good idea to make them so, it helps in a lot of scenarios, and this is one of them.

Comment: @Victor: if you like Dty's solution why don't you use something like `@shops[51..-1].each...`?

Comment: @Michael Kohl, the number in `[51..-1]` automatically refers to the ID?

Comment: No, but you could sort the array by id first: `@shops.sort_by(&:id).each[51..-1]...`.

Comment: @Michael Kohl, this is great. I tested and it works. Why not you answer this in full, then I choose your answer as solution? Thanks.

Comment: Glad it helped, posted as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested in the comment, I'll post this as an answer:

```
@shops.sort_by(&:id).each[50..-1] do |shop|
  # whatever you need to do
end
```

Comment: Actually, I think sorting in `find` level will give better performance. `@shops = Shops.find(:all, :order => "id ASC")`, then `@shops.each[50..-1]`. I start from 50 because the index is from 0 onwards. What do you tihnk?

Comment: Sure, if you can and want to modify the `find` statement, then this is the better approach.

Comment: I tried, it works well. Btw, it should be `@shops[50..-1].each` instead. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `with_index`

```
@shops.each_with_index |shop, i|
    # i will increment each time through the loop
end
```

Be aware that the index will start at 0. So to start with your 50th item you will want to start at index 49.

Comment: If OP uses 1.9 there's a separate `with_index` method, which can take a starting value: `something.each.with_index(1)...`.

Answer (score 0):

```
@shops.each do |shop|
    begin
        # some task here
    rescue
        # error
    end
end
```